# Изменить и продолжить

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка

Как сделать так чтобы в Visual Studio при изменении кода в режиме отладки, программа продолжила свое выполнение?
Жутко раздражает, что при малейшем изменении приходится перезапускать проект, т.к. я привык редактировать код в процессе отладки.

Comment: Но ведь это компилятор, как он может продолжить, если код поменялся? Интерпретатор может продолжить, потому что он что встретил, то и обработал, последовательно. А компилятор должен весь код пересобрать и заново запустить. Он не знает, что такое "продолжить", если поменялся и заново скомпилировался код.

Comment: Да, но вдруг есть какие-нибудь обходные пути, я никак не могу привыкнуть к такой отладке кода

Comment: Вообще-то в Visual Studio есть режим Edit and Continue, в котором изменения в исходниках на лету компилируются и применяются прямо в бегущем процессе (да, это фантастически сложно). Но он работает не со всеми методами / изменениями. Более новые версии Visual Studio более совершенны. Попробуйте обновить Visual Studio и попробовать на разных методах.

Comment: @Ruslan Программируйте на Python в Jupyter Notebook тогда, зачем вам C# и VS. )  Конечно, менять код на ходу удобно, но не все языки и среды разработки это позволяют. А некоторые специально для этого прямо сделаны.

Comment: И да, по возможности, пишите под новый рантайм, .NET 5, вот это всё: с ним Edit and Continue идёт по идее лучше.

Comment: Еще забыли в комментах выше упомянуть, что работает оно преимущественно с x64 приложениями. В .NET 6 (осенью) еще завезут фич по горячей перезагрузке кода.

Comment: У меня Edit and Continue работает только для классического .Net Framework. На .Net Core 3 и .Net 5 не работает. Тоже пока не понял почему..

Comment: Погуглил в англоязычном сообществе. Где-то писали, что это баг в студии. Только что обновился до 16.11.0 Preview 2.0 (Была 16.9.0 Preview какая-то). И что вы думаете? После внесения изменений рядом с кнопкой "продолжить" появляется кнопка с иконкой в виде огня "применить изменения". После её нажатия выполняется уже измененный код. Круто

Comment: Тоже не всегда могу понять, иногда небольшие изменения применяются и можно продолжить. И этого уже достаточно, потому что ошибаешься обычно как раз в мелочах. Но иногда ни в какую не хочет продолжать. Учился программированию на JS и симпатизирую Python, но работаю сейчас на .net. Очень мне нравилось писать кусок код в консоли, отрабатывать его, а потом уже переносить в редактор.

Comment: Кстати находил на сайте Microsoft песочницу C# вдруг кто не сталкивался, пример тут : https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values#code-try-2

Comment: https://habr.com/en/company/otus/blog/569094/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего особенного для этого делать не нужно, режим [Edit and Continue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2019) в Visual Studio существует и отлично работает. В версии 2012 и ранее он поддерживался только для 32-разрядных приложений. В современных версиях он работает при любой разрядности, и при любой поддерживаемой целевой платформе (.NET Framework, .NET Core и .NET 5). Реализована эта возможность путем отправки в работающий процесс изменений в метаданных и IL-коде методов, затронутых при редактировании, в особом недокументированном формате - так называемой "дельты", которая передается через функцию [ApplyEditAndContinue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/coreclr/vm/encee.cpp#L87) во внутреннем интерфейсе CLR с отладчиком.

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться этим режимом, нужно только приостановить выполнение программы (кнопкой "Прервать все" или Ctrl + Alt + Break), внести изменения, а затем нажать "Продолжить". В новых версиях студии можно просто редактировать код в реальном времени - изменения подчеркиваются зеленым, и при следующей остановке и запуске они будут применены. Но поддерживаются не любые изменения - см. [Supported code changes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2019). Изменения, которые можно выразить дельтой IL, обычно поддерживаются (например, изменения в коде внутри метода, не затрагивающие блоки исключений), тогда как изменения, затрагивающие методы в целом, например удаление параметров из метода, не поддерживаются. Если вы сделаете неподдерживаемое изменение, продолжить отладку не получится, придется пересобирать проект и запускать отладку заново. Кроме того, Edit and Continue не поддерживается при отладке кода с оптимизацией (по умолчанию она включена в конфигурации Release).

Answer (score 0):

Доступна новая Visual Studio 2022 Preview, которая отчасти решает эту проблему.